# What is the closed form of ridge regression with gaussian family in package "glmnet"

Tags: regression, glmnet

I take the deriavite of the beta in the "glmnet" with gaussian.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms9jU.png)

Then get a closed form like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0qFy.png)

When I use this form with the normalized X and normalized Y and get the same solution of the function "glmnet".

But why can't I get a approxmiate solution with the normalized X and center Y.

Here are about the gaussian family in the glmnet vignette.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX0mO.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUGNh.png)